# Checking if an element exists in a tuple and retrieving the other elements of tuple using Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I am new to Python.
I have a tuple
Tuple=(3,4,5)
I have a list.
List=[3,5]

I want the output to be 4 since [3,5] is present in (3,4,5)
How do I do this using Python?

Comment: Use a set difference operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your iterables to a set and then perform set difference.

```
In [459]: t = (3,4,5) 

In [460]: l = [3,5]

In [461]: set(t) - set(l) if all(x in t for x in l) else None
Out[461]: {4}
```

Comment: This doesn't exclude lists with no elements in the tuple.

Comment: @Prune Thanks, and sorry, had no choice but to echo you.

Comment: As long as we have a solid answer here for the archives, I'm happy.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_tuple = (3, 4, 5)
my_list = [3, 5]

# Check to see whether each item in your list is also in the tuple.    
if all(item in my_tuple for item in my_list):
    # Convert both to sets and print the difference.
    print set(my_tuple) - set(my_list)
```

Output:

```
set([4])
```